# window is not defined during build

Tags: reactjs, next.js, leaflet

I am making an IP Address Tracker using Next JS and leaflet.js. Every time I try to deploy my project in Vercel it shows me an error that says:

```
Build error occurred
ReferenceError: window is not defined
at /vercel/path0/node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet-src.js:227:19
```

I already imported my component dynamically but it still shows the same error.

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
const MapsNoSSR = dynamic(() => import("./MapsNoSSR.js"), { ssr: false });
```

This is my `MapsNoSSR.js` file:

```
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from "react-leaflet";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import "leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility/dist/leaflet-defaulticon- 
compatibility.css";
import "leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { ChangeView } from "./ChangeView.js";

const Maps = ({ results }) => {

return (
<MapContainer
  center={[geoData.lat, geoData.lng]}
  zoom={12}
  doubleClickZoom={true}
  scrollWheelZoom={true}
  dragging={true}
  animate={true}
  scrollWheelZoom={false}
  style={{
    height: "900px",
    width: "100%",
    position: "absolute",
    zIndex: "1",
   }}
 >
   {geoData.lat && geoData.lng && (
    <ChangeView coords={[geoData.lat, geoData.lng]} zoom={15} />
  )}

  <TileLayer
    url={`https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets- 
   v11/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x?access_token=`}
  />
  {geoData.lat && geoData.lng && (
    <Marker position={[geoData.lat, geoData.lng]}>
      <Popup position={[geoData.lat, geoData.lng]}>
        Current Position: {geoData.lat}, {geoData.lng}
      </Popup>
    </Marker>
  )}
</MapContainer>
 );
 };
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue, dynamically importing the `Maps` component should prevent that error from occurring. Are you sure you're not importing `react-leaflet` somewhere else?

Comment: I am pretty sure that I have imported it  from the correct file

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a way to make it work?

Comment: Also running into this

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same 'window is not defined' error when working with Nextjs and leaflet. It appears that you're handling the dynamic component correctly, which is the first step to addressing this issue.

But from the looks of it you've made the same mistake I did which was to store my map component in the pages directory. [Nextjs likes to pre-compile the pages directory](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages), which is why you're seeing this error.

To resolve this issue, please move your MapsNoSSR component out of the Pages directory and into a separate directory, like a new Components directory.